# How to solve the visibility change innerHTML text problem

Tags: javascript

hey guys i have a question like if we give label tags visibility as hidden and we want to change its inner text and display it how to do that in java script.i was going through the basics and i did not find anything please help

```
<label id="hey" style="color:red;visibility:hidden">
  Visibility check
</label>

<script>
<!-- assume we have a button-->
function checks(){
  var s = document.getElementById("hey").style.visibility="visible";
  s.innerHTML="Checks";
  <!-- changing my text {this does not work} -->    
}
</script>
```

Can you solve this? this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript,

```js
var a, b;
a = b = 2;
```

assigns the value `2` to both `a` and `b`.

Hence, in your code, not only are you changing the style property of the element to `visible`, you are assigning this value to `s` as well.

What you intended, however, is to keep a reference of the element in `s` and then mutate it accordingly without losing the reference -

```js
var s = document.getElementById("hey");
s.style.visibility = "visible";
s.innerHTML = "Checks";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is the reason y i cant do this var str = document.getElementById("id_name").style.visibility="visible"; str.innerHTML="check"; y does this not work/?

Answer (score 0):

You created a function, but never called it.

Html:

```
<label id="hey" style="color:red;visibility:hidden">
  Visibility check
</label>
```

JS:

```
function checks() {
  var s = document.getElementById("hey")
  s.style.visibility = "visible";
  s.innerHTML = "Checks";
}

checks()
```

JSfiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/tc7rp42b/1/

Comment: thanks manh !!! the function actually we we have to assume that thers a button which calls the function so i didnt write that part xD